# Share private view-access Google Calendar information

Tags: google-calendar

My spouse and I share Google calendars to coordinate schedules.  A group I'm in shares a private calendar with me that has information about group events.

Is there any way to make events on this private calendar visible to my spouse without specifically adding her to the group?

I'm trying to avoid making a personal copy of group events on MY calendar so that they are visible to her.

Comment: Unless she adds that private calendar to her own account, you're limited to copying events from that calendar to a calendar you are sharing with her.

Comment: If you have the "make changes AND manage sharing" privilege then you can share a read-only version of the calendar with your spouse (perhaps one that hides the details if required).